# how to convert birdseed to genabel

Tags: r

I want to use R package GenAbel for the quality control of SNP data sets.

For this, I have ~ 100 processed SNP6 datasets (birdseed.txt). The data looks like this:

```
Composite Element REF   Call    Confidence

SNP_A-2131660            1   0.0545

SNP_A-1967418            2   0.0675
```

Then, I want to use R package GenAbel with this file, but I don't know how to convert this file to GenAbel format.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you at least describe the "GenAbel format"? How does your file need to be formatted?

Comment: Thanks MrFlick :) OK. I want to use "check.marker" this function in GenAbel package with birdseed format files. Then, I think I should convert my birdseed files to "snp.data" format. Am I correct?

Comment: I think "convert.snp.affymetrix"this function could be an option. But the format is a bit strange : convert.snp.affymetrix(dir="where_is_our_aff_files", map="map_file", outfile="output.raw", skipaffym=3). They need one file (mapping file), then where can I put my input files (such as birdseed files)?

Comment: So do you have one file per person? Do you have chr/pos information for each SNP?

Comment: Yes! I have one file per person (and I can merge them together) and also have chr/position information for each SNP :)